# Split up `...` arguments and distribute to multiple functions

Tags: r

Using the following function `foo()` as a simple example, I'd like to distribute the values given in `...` two different functions, if possible.

```
foo <- function(x, y, ...) {
    list(sum = sum(x, ...), grep = grep("abc", y, ...))
}
```

In the following example, I would like `na.rm` to be passed to `sum()`, and `value` to be passed to `grep()`. But I get an error for an unused argument in `grep()`.

```
X <- c(1:5, NA, 6:10)
Y <- "xyzabcxyz"
foo(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# Error in grep("abc", y, ...) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)
```

It seems like the arguments were sent to `grep()` first.  Is that correct? I would think R would see and evaluate `sum()` first, and return an error for that case.

Furthermore, when trying to split up the arguments in `...`, I ran into trouble.  `sum()`'s formal arguments are `NULL` because it is a `.Primitive`, and therefore I cannot use

```
names(formals(sum)) %in% names(list(...))
```

I also don't want to assume that the leftover arguments from

```
names(formals(grep)) %in% names(list(...))
```

are to automatically be passed to `sum()`.

**How can I safely and efficiently distribute `...` arguments to multiple functions so that no unnecessary evaluations are made?**

In the long-run, I'd like to be able to apply this to functions with a long list of `...` arguments, similar to those of `download.file()` and `scan()`.

Comment: The exact same `...` values are sent to both function. `sum(X, na.rm = TRUE, value = TRUE)` does not return an error (note that `sum(1, na.rm = TRUE, value = TRUE)==2`), but `grep("abc",Y, na.rm = TRUE, value = TRUE)` does.R will not change the `...` based on what's actually used by a function. If you want to split up the parameters, you will have to do it by yourself.

Comment: For primitive functions, you can retrieve the arguments using, for example, `formals(args(sum))`.

Comment: @RichieCotton - That is really useful.  Thank you.  Surprised that I've never seen that used before.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Separate Lists** If you really want to pass different sets of parameters to different functions then it's probably cleaner to specify separate lists:

```
foo <- function(x, y, sum = list(), grep = list()) {
 list(sum = do.call("sum", c(x, sum)), grep = do.call("grep", c("abc", y, grep)))
}

# test

X <- c(1:5, NA, 6:10)
Y <- "xyzabcxyz"
foo(X, Y, sum = list(na.rm = TRUE), grep = list(value = TRUE))

## $sum
## [1] 55
## 
## $grep
## [1] "xyzabcxyz"
```

**Hybrid list / ...** An alternative is that we could use ... for one of these and then specify the other as a list, particularly in the case that one of them is frequently used and the other is infrequently used.  The frequently used one would be passed via ... and the infrequently used via a list. e.g.

```
foo <- function(x, y, sum = list(), ...) {
 list(sum = do.call("sum", c(x, sum)), grep = grep("abc", y, ...))
}

foo(X, Y, sum = list(na.rm = TRUE), value = TRUE)
```

Here are a couple of examples of the hybrid approach from R itself:

i) The `mapply` function takes that approach using both `...` and a `MoreArgs` list:

```
> args(mapply)
function (FUN, ..., MoreArgs = NULL, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
NULL
```

ii) `nls` also takes this approach using both `...` and the `control` list:

```
> args(nls)
function (formula, data = parent.frame(), start, control = nls.control(), 
    algorithm = c("default", "plinear", "port"), trace = FALSE, 
    subset, weights, na.action, model = FALSE, lower = -Inf, 
    upper = Inf, ...) 
NULL
```

Answer (score 17):

1. Why does `grep` error before `sum`?

   See that `sum` is a lot more accommodating with its arguments:

   ```
   X <- c(1:5, NA, 6:10)
   sum(X, na.rm = TRUE, value = TRUE)
   ## [1] 56
   ```

   It doesn't failed because it doesn't care about other named arguments, so the `value = TRUE` simplifies to just `TRUE` which sums to 1. Incidentally:

   ```
   sum(X, na.rm = TRUE)
   ## [1] 55
   ```
2. How to split `...` to different functions?

   One method (that is very prone to error) is to look for the args for the target functions. For instance:

   ```
   foo <- function(x, y, ...){
       argnames <- names(list(...))
       sumargs <- intersect(argnames, names(as.list(args(sum))))
       grepargs <- intersect(argnames, names(as.list(args(grep))))
       list(sum = do.call(sum, c(list(x), list(...)[sumargs])),
            grep = do.call(grep, c(list("abc", y), list(...)[grepargs])))
   }
   ```

   This is prone to error anytime the arguments a function *uses* are not properly reported by `args`, such as S3 objects. As an example:

   ```
   names(as.list(args(plot)))
   ## [1] "x"   "y"   "..." ""   
   names(as.list(args(plot.default)))
   ##  [1] "x"           "y"           "type"        "xlim"        "ylim"       
   ##  [6] "log"         "main"        "sub"         "xlab"        "ylab"       
   ## [11] "ann"         "axes"        "frame.plot"  "panel.first" "panel.last" 
   ## [16] "asp"         "..."         ""
   ```

   In this case, you could substitute the appropriate S3 function. Because of this, I don't have a generalized solution for this (though I don't know that it does or does not exist).

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Consider using the "trick" implemented in `plot.default` and elsewhere.  It is tried and tested.

```r
foo <- function(x, y, ...) {
    localSum <- function(..., value) sum(...)
    localGrep <- function(..., na.rm) grep(...)
    list(sum = localSum(x, ...), grep = localGrep("abc", y, ...))
}

X <- c(1:5, NA, 6:10)
Y <- "xyzabcxyz"
foo(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE, value = TRUE)
## $sum
## [1] 55
## 
## $grep
## [1] "xyzabcxyz"
##
```

---

I am a bit shocked that the "trick" used by `plot.default` hasn't come up here yet. (Maybe it is mentioned elsewhere?)

Recall that `plot.default` must process the optional arguments of the internal `plot.xy` (for points and lines) *as well as* those of `plot.window`, `box`, `axis`, and `title`.  These are all handled through one `...` argument.

Importantly, when we pass (say) `lwd = 6` to `plot.default` to widen lines in the plot region, `plot.default` must ensure that this argument is *not* seen by `box` and `axis`, which use `lwd` to set the width of the plot region border and axis lines.  Hence:

```r
> plot.default(0:1, 0:1, type = "l", lwd = 6)
```

[image]

This feature of `plot.default` is implemented using "local" versions of the subfunctions `plot.window`, `box`, `axis`, and `title`.  The local versions are just wrappers designed to filter out arguments in `...` that the subfunctions cannot be allowed to see (in this case `col`, `bg`, `pch`, `cex`, `lty`, and `lwd`).

```r
> plot.default
function (x, y = NULL, type = "p", xlim = NULL, ylim = NULL, 
    log = "", main = NULL, sub = NULL, xlab = NULL, ylab = NULL, 
    ann = par("ann"), axes = TRUE, frame.plot = axes, panel.first = NULL, 
    panel.last = NULL, asp = NA, xgap.axis = NA, ygap.axis = NA, 
    ...) 
{
    localAxis <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) Axis(...)
    localBox <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) box(...)
    localWindow <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) plot.window(...)
    localTitle <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) title(...)
    xlabel <- if (!missing(x)) 
        deparse1(substitute(x))
    ylabel <- if (!missing(y)) 
        deparse1(substitute(y))
    xy <- xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log)
    xlab <- if (is.null(xlab)) 
        xy$xlab
    else xlab
    ylab <- if (is.null(ylab)) 
        xy$ylab
    else ylab
    xlim <- if (is.null(xlim)) 
        range(xy$x[is.finite(xy$x)])
    else xlim
    ylim <- if (is.null(ylim)) 
        range(xy$y[is.finite(xy$y)])
    else ylim
    dev.hold()
    on.exit(dev.flush())
    plot.new()
    localWindow(xlim, ylim, log, asp, ...)
    panel.first
    plot.xy(xy, type, ...)
    panel.last
    if (axes) {
        localAxis(if (is.null(y)) 
            xy$x
        else x, side = 1, gap.axis = xgap.axis, ...)
        localAxis(if (is.null(y)) 
            x
        else y, side = 2, gap.axis = ygap.axis, ...)
    }
    if (frame.plot) 
        localBox(...)
    if (ann) 
        localTitle(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, 
            ...)
    invisible()
}
<bytecode: 0x10b813010>
<environment: namespace:graphics>
```

Let's take `localTitle` as an example:

```r
localTitle <- function(..., col, bg, pch, cex, lty, lwd) title(...)
```

`plot.default` passes all of the arguments in `...` to `localTitle` when it calls

```r
localTitle(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)
```

but `title` only ever sees those arguments not named `col`, `bg`, `pch`, `cex`, `lty`, or `lwd`, since those are included as formal arguments of `localTitle`.

Notably, this approach to processing `...` has minimal overhead as it takes full advantage of lazy evaluation.  None of the expressions in `...` are evaluated until they are used by the subfunctions.

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass the `...` argument to another function, if that other function includes all named arguments that you pass to `...` or if it has a `...` argument itself. So for `sum`, this is no problem (`args(sum)` returns `function (..., na.rm = FALSE)`). On the other hand `grep` has neither `na.rm` nor `...` as an  argument.

```
args(grep)
# function (pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE, 
#     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
```

This does not include `...` and also does not include a named argument `na.rm` either. A simple solution is to just define your own function `mygrep` as follows:

```
mygrep <- function (pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE, 
                    fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE, ...)
  grep(pattern, x, ignore.case, perl, value, fixed, useBytes, invert)
```

Then it seems to work:

```
foo <- function(x, y, ...){
  list(sum = sum(x, ...), grep = mygrep("abc", y, ...))
}
X <- c(1:5, NA, 6:10)
Y <- "xyzabcxyz"
foo(X, Y, na.rm = TRUE, value = TRUE)

# $sum
# [1] 56
# 
# $grep
# [1] "xyzabcxyz"
```

Comment: The first sentence isn't right - you can pass `...` even if the other function doesn't take `...`. For example:
`add <- function(x, y)  x + y ;  f <- function(...) add(...) ;  f(3,4)`

Comment: @wch: Thanks for pointing that out. Changed the first sentence accordingly.

Comment: First paragraph is still misleading

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not directly the original question but could be helpful to others who experience a similar problem with *their own* functions (as opposed to *existing* functions like `sum` and `grep`).

[@shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2591234/shadow)'s answer contains an insight that points to a very simple solution in such cases: just make sure your nested functions have `...` as an argument and you won't get the `unused argument` error.

For example:

```
nested1 <- function(x, a) {
 x + a
}

nested2 <- function(x, b) {
 x - b
}

f <- function(x, ...) {
 if (x >= 0) {
  nested1(x, ...)
 } else {
  nested2(x, ...)
 }
}
```

If we call `f(x = 2, a = 3, b = 4)` we get an error: `Error in nested1(x, ...) : unused argument (b = 4)`.

But just add a `...` to the formals of `nested1` and `nested2` and run again:

```
nested1 <- function(x, a, ...) {
 x + a
}

nested2 <- function(x, b, ...) {
 x - b
}
```

Now, `f(x = 2, a = 3, b = 4)` yields the desired result: `5`. Problem solved.