# how to pass columns in data.frame to functions having dplyr's function inside

Tags: r, function, arguments, dplyr

```
x <- y <- 1:5
df = data.frame(m=x,n=y)

myfun <- function(data, var) {
  library(dplyr)
   select(data, var)
}


myfun(df, m)
```

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'm' not found

Comment: Your first version I think actually works, you simply passed `select`  column indices that don't exist.

Comment: However, both calls don't work for me. no clue

Comment: I will repeat, you created a df with two columns and then asked for columns 1:5.

Comment: @joran if change to df = data.frame(m=x,n=y), and call myfun(df, m), still error

Comment: You didn't understand my comment at all. Your first example is attempting to select nonexistent columns from your data frame. The issue is passing the vector 1:5, not the names of the columns.

Comment: ...namely that you were inadvertently attempting to use select with numeric indices, rather than column names. And I was pointing out that that WILL work, I think, unless you request nonexistent columns.

Comment: Best just to wait until I've done this: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/352

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richards answer makes it possible to bypass an arbitrary number of arguments. But to control each argument of such a select call separately you have to know:
In `select(data, m)`, m is **not** a variable which has an assigned value at this point! It is just a symbol which gets some meaning in the context of the dataframe "data". `myfun(df, m)` will fail as soon as the parameter `m` is used (which is the case in the select-call), because `m` has no value (or the value from the global environment, which you surely do not want!) Internally, dplyr will use the `substitute` function to convert it to a symbol (instead of evaluating it). After var is converted to a symbol (or a call, for e.g. selections like `m:n`), you can compose and evaluate a new select-call with `do.call`.

For your example code this implies:

```
x <- y <- 1:5
df = data.frame(m=x,n=y)

myfun <- function(data, var) {
  library(dplyr)
  var <- substitute(var)
  do.call('select', list(data, var))
}


myfun(df, m)
```

The generalization to more arguments is straight forward.

For an arbitrary number of arguments which you want to convert to symbols or calls you can use

```
myfun <- function(...) {
  args <- substitute(list(...))
  # Now args[i] is a symbol/call representing the i-th argument
}
```

Comment: Using `do.call()` in this way is highly not recommended - it eliminates many of the advantages of dplyr because it must construct at least one (and maybe two) extra copies of the data.

Answer (score 0):

`select` uses `select.data.frame`, a data frame method. The second argument to `select` is a `...` list so that arguments can be passed to other methods. Your function uses the name `var` in its second argument, and because of `dplyr`'s `.()` function, the base R variance function `var` is being passed to other functions inside `select`.

Long story short, change your argument names.  I would go with

```
myfun <- function(z, ...) select(z, ...)
myfun(df, x)
myfun(df, y)
```

You can also use the `select` methods

```
> select.myfun <- function(.data, ...) UseMethod("select")
> myfun(df, exclude = "x")
> methods(select)[6]
[1] "select.myfun"
```

As a shameless plug, I'll refer you to [a question I asked about `...` arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376197/split-up-arguments-and-distribute-to-multiple-functions). There are two very good explanations in the answers.

*Edit* As requested, a look at `.()`

```
> `.`
function (..., .env = parent.frame()) 
{
    structure(as.list(match.call()[-1]), env = .env, class = "quoted")
}
<environment: namespace:plyr>

> .(x)
List of 1
 $ x: symbol x
 - attr(*, "env")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "quoted"
```

Comment: follow on that, for example, if I have two select in my function. how can I pass different args to each one.

Comment: @Scriven could you point out where .() function is. I could not find it in the dplyr documentation. Thanks