# Sending args in ellipses (...) to different destinations

Tags: r

From time to time I need to allow a user to add optional arguments via ...  In some cases these optional arguments are intended for `plot()`, and sometimes they are intended for some other function called within my function.  I wrote the following function which sorts the arguments into those that go with `plot()` and those that don't:

```
dotsForPlots <- function(..., plot = TRUE) {
    dots <- list(...)
    dotnames <- names(dots)
    dfp <- names(par()) # dfp = dots for plots
    # add select args for plot.default
    dfp <- c(dfp, "main", "xlim", "ylim", "xlab", "ylab", "type")
    if (plot) pass <- which(dotnames %in% dfp)
    if (!plot) pass <- which(!dotnames %in% dfp)
    return(dots[pass])
}
```

This works well enough:

```
tst <- dotsForPlots(cex = 2, noise = 5, junk = "hello",
                    lty = 3, plot = TRUE, main = "Test Plot")
str(tst)
```

And here is a function that uses this:

```
foo <- function(x, y, ...) {
    dnp <- dotsForPlots(..., plot = FALSE) # to go to jitter
    dnp$x <- y # has to match eventual function call
    y <- do.call(jitter, args = dnp)
    dfp <- dotsForPlots(...) # to go to plot
    dfp$x <- x
    dfp$y <- y
    do.call(plot, dfp)  
    }
```

And running it

```
foo(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, cex = 2, lty = 2, factor = 10,
    main = "Hello", ylab = "", type = "b")
```

Produces the desired output.

Now the questions:

1. Is there a built-in way to do this / did I just reinvent the wheel?   Seems like there might be but I couldn't find it.
2. Is there a simpler option in the 2nd function than the `do.call` approach? I'm thinking of something that just allows me to coerce `dfp` in some way that I can just use `plot(x, y, "modified dfp")` so to speak.

Comment: You might get some ideas from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376197/split-up-arguments-and-distribute-to-multiple-functions

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks, I'll study that answer, which I missed.