# Giving arguments from "..." argument to right function in R

Tags: r, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a function to compute the correlation of  matrix of both categorical and continuous variables:

```
correlation <- function(matrix, ...) {
    xx <- do.call(rbind, lapply(colnames(mtrc), function(ex_i) {
        ty_i <- wtype(matrix, ex_i)
        yy <- sapply(colnames(mtrc), function(ex_j) {
            ty_j <- wtype(matrix, ex_j)

            if(ty_i == "numeric" & ty_j == "numeric") {
                cor(mtrc[ , c(ex_i, ex_j)], ...)[1, 2]
            } else if(ty_i == "factor" & ty_j == "factor") {
                cramersV(table(mtrc[ , c(ex_i, ex_j)]), ...)
            } else {
                fm <- paste(ex_i, "~", ex_j)
                if(ty_i == "factor") {
                    fm <- paste(ex_j, "~", ex_i)
                }
                fm <- lm(fm, data = mtrc[ , c(ex_i, ex_j)], ...)
                lm.beta(fm)
            }
        })
        names(yy) <- colnames(mtrc)
        yy
    }))
    rownames(xx) <- colnames(mtrc)
    xx
}
```

My question is how to pass, properly, the argument `...` to `cor`, `cramerV` and `lm`. Since the argument's names of these three functions do not match if the user gives an argument for `cor` and there is a categorical variable in the matrix, the `cramerV` or `lm` raises an error (*unused argument...*).

So... I'm open to any solution or idea you can have.

Comment: Do `dots <- list(...)` and check, e.g., which of the elements match with `formalArgs(lm)` and subset the list to these. Add the `fm` and `data` parameters to this list and call `lm` using `do.call`. I would show you how, but you don't provide a reproducible example.

Comment: You might also find the functions `dots` or `named_dots` in the `pryr` package useful for this kind of task.

Answer (score 2):

I did not realize that there was an excellent question by Richard Scriven at 2014: [Split up `...` arguments and distribute to multiple functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25376197/4891738), when I made my answer below. So yes, this is a duplicated question. But I will keep my answer here, as it represents what I thought (and what I think).

---

**Original answer**

I think this is better, by giving your `correlation` function a finer control:

```
correlation <- function(matrix, cor.opt = list(), cramersV.opt = list(), lm.opt = list()) {
    xx <- do.call(rbind, lapply(colnames(mtrc), function(ex_i) {
        ty_i <- wtype(matrix, ex_i)
        yy <- sapply(colnames(mtrc), function(ex_j) {
            ty_j <- wtype(matrix, ex_j)

            if(ty_i == "numeric" & ty_j == "numeric") {
                do.call("cor", c(list(x = mtrc[ , c(ex_i, ex_j)]), cor.opt))[1, 2]
            } else if(ty_i == "factor" & ty_j == "factor") {
                do.call("cramersV", c(list(x = table(mtrc[ , c(ex_i, ex_j)])), cramersV.opt))
            } else {
                fm <- paste(ex_i, "~", ex_j)
                if(ty_i == "factor") {
                    fm <- paste(ex_j, "~", ex_i)
                }
                fm <- do.call("lm", c(list(formula = fm, data = mtrc[ , c(ex_i, ex_j)]), lm.opt))
                lm.beta(fm)
            }
        })
        names(yy) <- colnames(mtrc)
        yy
    }))
    rownames(xx) <- colnames(mtrc)
    xx
}
```

You can pass different arguments intended for different functions via arguments `cor.opt`, `cramersV.opt` and `lm.opt`. Then, inside your function `correlation`, use `do.call()` for all relevant function call.

---

**Comment**

I like @Roland's idea. He chooses to use `...`, while splitting `list(...)` according to formal arguments of different functions. On the other hand, I have asked you to manually specify those arguments into different lists. In the end, both of us ask you to use `do.call()` for function call.

Roland's idea is broadly applicable, as it is easier to extend to more functions requiring `...`.