# How to pass additional parameters via ... to statistic parameter in boot()

Tags: r, parameter-passing, optional-arguments

I am trying to determine how to pass additional parameters to the parameter `statistic` in the function `boot()` in R, using `...`. In reading `?boot`, it says that
"*the first argument passed will always be the original data. The second will be a vector of indices, frequencies or weights which define the bootstrap sample.... Any further arguments can be passed to* `statistic` *through the* `...` *argument*. Yet I'm not sure how this will actually look in practice.

Here's some example code -- `statFun` is a function which takes in some data and returns the mean. If extra parameters are passed through the `...` command, it centers the data around those extra parameters and then returns the mean:

```
statFun <- function(funData, indices, ...)
{
  # Check to see if extra parameters
  extraPar <- list(...)
  if(extraPar[[1]])
  {
    result <- mean(funData[indices] - extraPar[[2]])
  }else
  {
    result <- mean(funData[indices])
  }

  # Return the value
  return(result)
}

# Testing statFun
testData <- 1:20 ; testIndices <- length(testData) 
statFun(testData, testIndices, FALSE) # Returns 10.5
statFun(testData, testIndices, TRUE, mean(testData)) # Returns 0
```

Now, if I try to apply this function within `boot`, I run into problems:

```
boot(testData, statFun, R = 100)
```

which gives me `Error in extraPar[[1]] : subscript out of bounds`. If I try passing `FALSE` into `statFun`, but still get the same error. I can understand how my scoping is not correct, but how would I overcome this? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124900/is-there-a-way-to-use-two-statements-in-a-function-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072365/how-to-pass-arguments-into-function-within-a-function-in-r) post to understand how to use `...` a little better, but I seem to be missing something glaringly obvious...

This is my first SO post, so please let me know if my question doesn't follow the guidelines. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I get results 20 and 9.5 (which I would expect).

Comment: I think the help means you can pass multiple arguments via the `...`, but to actually do this , and to be passed on to boot , you should probably name them : so use `statFun <- function(funData, indices, center=FALSE, val = NULL){` , and change the rest of your function accordingly. You then call boot with `boot(testData, statFun, center=TRUE, val=mean(testData), R = 100)`

Comment: in fact the help for the `...` argumnet says *"Other **named arguments** for statistic which are passed unchanged each time it is called*" (emphasis mine)

Comment: Yeah -- I just started working on it and changed my `statFun` to include named parameters, rather than making them ambiguous through `...`, just like you mentioned [user20650](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650). Thanks for the help, got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250190/user20650) and reading `?boot` examples a little more carefully, I figured out what was needed -- just to make sure that my parameters within `statFun` are named and that I refer to these names in my call of `boot`. Simple stuff:

```
statFun <- function(funData, indices, addPars, centerMean)
    {
      # Check to see if extra parameters
      if(addPars)
      {
        result <- mean(funData[indices] - centerMean)
      }else
      {
        result <- mean(funData[indices])
      }

      # Return the value
      return(result)
    }
```

Now, when I apply this within boot and use the names `addPars` and `centerMean`, I get what I would expect:

```
boot(testData, statFun, R = 100, extraPar = TRUE, numCenter = mean(testData)) 
# Returns boot object of data centered around the mean.
```

Certainly understand `...` more now.